# Installshield leaves byte compiled files behind on uninstalltion

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation, basic-msi

I have build Installshield Basic MSI project with some python files as components. On uninstallation it leaves byte compiled files behind.

I can see one of way of doing it is to write `Installscript` which will get called on uninstallation. Is there any elegent way of doing it?

Comment: Where are these files installed? If you install to "My Documents" I would not recommend removing anything since this is considered user data. If you install underneath the Program Files hierarchy, you will need admin rights during the compile operation in order to create the files.

Comment: @Glytzhkof this files gets created when I install python windows (It compiles the .py and created .pyc) service and I also write some logs into file.

Comment: As already stated the MSI mechanism for this is the RemoveFile table. You specify what files should be deleted on uninstall. Be careful with wild-cards as it might delete more than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer only removes files it installs, and other ones it's been explicitly told about. Thus adding records to the [RemoveFile table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201.aspx) is the canonical way to do this. InstallShield 2014 adds options for this in the Files and Folders view and in the component's view, and this is available in earlier versions via the Direct Editor.

Comment: Thanks for addressing this issue.. Will look at it and get back to you